# Modelbinding of IList in ASP.Net MVC Final Release

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding, model

There are a lot of examples on how to use the built-in Model-binding capabilities to automatically get a List of items. But they all refer to the Beta-releases of ASP.net MVC. It is also mentioned that there has been a change in this Model Binding but so far I was not able to find a good source on how it now works in the Final Release. And I`m far away of beeing capable to interprete the source code :-)

So would be great if someone could explain me how I would need to prepare a List of values in the View to get it nicely back in an IList of specific objects.

appreciate your help

Maik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View:

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm("Retrieve", "Home")) %> { %>
<% var counter = 0; %>
    <% foreach (var app in newApps) { %>
    <tr>
        <td><%=Html.CheckBox(String.Format("myAppList[{0}].Id", counter), app.ApplicationId) %></td>
        <!-- ... -->
        <td><%=Html.Input(String.Format("myAppList[{0}].SomeProperty1", counter), app.SomeProperty1) %></td>
        <td><%=Html.Input(String.Format("myAppList[{0}].SomePropertyN", counter), app.SomePropertyN) %></td>
        <% counter = counter + 1; %>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
    <input type"submit" />
<% } %>
```

Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Retrieve(IList<MyAppObject> myAppList)
```

Comment: Ouch, that was almost to easy. Thanks for your help.